# Add custom menus in wordpress

Tags: css, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am just a newbie to the wordpress. I have my design some thing like this(sample image attached). So can some one tell me how to get my menu like this. You can see in the left side menus no drop down menu is there. But in right side you can see the drop down menus. I am currently working with wordpress twenty eleven theme.[image]

Comment: be more specific, what have tried and what you want.

Comment: @jogesh_p thanks for the reply. I want two different types of menu in the menu section.As you can see the attached image the left side menu doesnot have any dropdown and different style but in rightside manu it has different style other then the left.

Comment: but i can't find any attachment??

Comment: the image is attached with the question. Just refresh your browser. I have attached the image with the quetion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 separate menus. Add support for 2 menus in your theme

1)in your theme's functions.php add following code

```
register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu');
register_nav_menu( 'secondary', 'Secondary Menu');
```

2)then call these two menus side-by-side in header.php

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) );
```

Rest, you gonna have to do the css to make them appear in the same line and with different font size etc..

3) from wp-admin area create two menus and assign them to primary and secondary menu
4) in your 2nd menu (the one which wud appear to the right), make sure dropdown links like 'payroll software', 'w2 software' are under the menu item 'Resources'

I guess that should do it...